# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}-1}{2\tan^{-1} (x^2)-\pi}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ e^{\frac{1}{x^2}} -1}{\frac{1}{x^2}} \frac{1}{(2\tan^{-1}(x^2)-\pi)x^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2(2\tan^{-1} x^2 -\pi)}$$
How do I proceed?

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hôpital's rule?  The first one is 0/0, so maybe try that and see where you get

Comment: what about putting $x^2=\tan \theta$ and letting $\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}-$

Comment: L'Hospital since you have an undeterminate case $0/0$

Comment: What do you mean ? Not able you mean you dont know how ? you have a fraction $1/x^2$ at the numerator and artcan at the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here

$$\frac{ e^{\frac{1}{x^2}} -1}{\frac{1}{x^2}} \frac{1}{\left(2\tan^{-1}(x^2)-\pi\right)x^2}$$

we have that by standard limit

$$\frac{ e^{\frac{1}{x^2}} -1}{\frac{1}{x^2}} \to 1$$

and by $\arctan x = \frac \pi 2 -\arctan \frac1x$

$$\frac{1}{\left(2\tan^{-1}(x^2)-\pi\right)x^2}=-\frac12\frac{\frac1{x^2}}{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)} \to -\frac12$$

---

To proceed by l'Hospital by $\frac1{x^2}=t \to 0$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}-1}{2\tan^{-1} (x^2)-\pi}=\lim_{t\to 0 }\frac{e^{t}-1}{2\tan^{-1} \left(\frac1t\right)-\pi}=\lim_{t\to 0 }\frac{e^{t}}{-\frac2{t^2+1}}=-\frac12$$

Comment: Can you demonstrate the L’Hospital rule as well? I am having a hard time apply it

Comment: @Aditya To prove by l'Hospital just take $\frac1{x^2}=t \to 0$ to simplify the caclulation.

Comment: @user The last limit is not correct. You should have  $$-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\frac1{x^2}}{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)}$$

Comment: @Äres Yes of course! Thanks I've fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Apply l'Hôpital's rule:
$$L=\lim\limits_ {x \to \infty} \dfrac {x^{-2}} {2\arctan x^2 -\pi}=\lim\limits_ {x \to \infty} \dfrac {-2x^{-3}} {2\dfrac {2x}{x^4+1}}$$
$$L==\lim\limits_ {x \to \infty} -{\dfrac {x^4}{2x^4}}=-\dfrac 12$$

Answer (score 0):

```
Limit[(Exp[-(1/x^2)] - 1)/(1/x^2) 1/((ArcTan[x^2] - π) x^2), 
 x -> 0]
1/π

Limit[(Exp[-(1/x^2)] - 1)/(1/x^2) , x -> 0]
0

Limit[ (ArcTan[x^2] - \[Pi]) x^2, x -> 0]
0
```

So this is a quotient 0/0 and the rule of l'Hospital applies.

```
Series[(ArcTan[x^2] - π) x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
SeriesData[x, 0, {-Pi}, 2, 3, 1]
```

[image]

```
Series[Exp[-(1/x^2)] - 1, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

This has to be developed as:

[image]

This give in the rule of l'Hospital:

```
-x^2/-πx^2 -> 1/π
```

So the above shown result is clear and prooved.

```
{Plot[{(Exp[-(1/x^2)] - 1)/(1/x^2) 1/((ArcTan[x^2] - \[Pi]) x^2), 
   N@1/\[Pi]}, {x, 0, 1}], N@1/\[Pi]}
```

[image: Plot near zero of the given quotient]

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(\exp\frac{1}{x^2}-1)}{2\arctan(x^2)-\pi}=\frac{1}{2}$$

The quotient is alreay "-0.5001" at "x=50".

Comment: $x \to \infty$ and not $x \to 0$